# Deploying Desktop Application with its database and other DLL programs

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed a desktop application (in VS 2010 with SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5) in c# which uses NITGEN's SDK for fingerprint scanning and its prerequisit dll file.

I created a new Data source, i.e. my created .sdf file, (Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5) while adding a new connection.

I dont see this .sdf file in "Application Files" Window, from "publish" tab of my Project's properties window.

I want to add this DB file to be deployed with my application along with the NITGEN's SDK and other dll file.

Also, How can I make my application download the prerequisites from my application's installer folder itself?

Any suggestion would be of great help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a deployment project from within the New Project option of the File menu.

Here's how: [`Walkthrough: Deploying a Windows-based Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k3bb4tfd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Plus, you ought to include your SDF Compact Database file into your project, then compile/build it. You will get your SDF file output into your bin directory or wherever your output directory is located.

You may also want to read on ClickOnce: [`ClickOnce Deployment for Windows Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yhbs0ya%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

After you're through with these, you shall be able to properly deploy your app.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the .sdf file in the Solution Explorer, it should be set to 'Content' and 'Copy if newer' (or 'Copy always').

Answer (score 0):

As Will outlined, the best is to use ClickOnce... It will allow you to download the pre-requirements and add all the resources (DB, ...) to your application.